# Qt layouting problem

Tags: qt, layout, qt4

Im implementing a Widget which is basically a list of buttons (which represent a file structure). It looks like this:

```
[[recentFolder]    // bar 
[(stretch)
[folderA],         // foo
[folderB],         // programs
[folderC],         // c:
(stretch)]
[rootDir]]         // my computer
```

I hope you can see the three widgets in my layout: A folderbutton for the most recent folder at the top, a folderbutton for the root folder at the bottom and a widget which displays many folderbuttons in the middle. All folderbuttons are fixed width and height. I added stretch areas at the top/bottom of the center widget because thats the only widget which should be able to resize (expanding policy in height). But when I resize the parent widget, it looks like this:

```
[[recentFolder]    // bar
// empty space does not
// belong to any child
[(stretch)
[folderA],         // foo
[folderB],         // programs
[folderC],         // c:
(stretch)]
// empty space does not
// belong to any child
[rootDir]]         // my computer
```

which means the center widget does not get any resize event at all. I need it to resize like that:

```
[[recentFolder]    // bar
[
// child was resized
(stretch)
[folderA],         // foo
[folderB],         // programs
[folderC],         // c:
(stretch)
// child was resized
]
[rootDir]]         // my computer
```

As you can (should) see, my stretch areas have no effect at all and do not work as I thougth they would. Im coming from .NET and miss the way how I could dock controls in the parent so they use up all the existing space. Any idea how to do this in Qt 4?

Right now im calling `setGeometry()` on my center child within the parents resize event, which works but bypasses the layout manager.

Comment: What is (stretch), is it QSpacer? If so, remove them and set stretch factors on three widgets properly.

Comment: Yes, its a QSpacer. I already tried .setStretch and .setStretchFactor, but without success. This is driving me mad! :/

Comment: QSpacer's purpose is to add empty space, like it did. How do you set stretch factors, have you tried 0 for recentFolder and rootDir and 1 for three inner buttons?

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. However, have a close look at my "drawings" again. I added QSpacer to the center widget in order to let it resize. But whats happening is the opposite: the QSpacer stay at 0px heigth and the layout manager creates new empty space BETWEEN my widgets which prevents the central widget from getting resize events.

Comment: Closer look helps :). Stretch factor of 1 on buttons is irrelevant because their height is fixed. But it's strange that QSpacers aren't resized, do they have non-zero stretch factor?

Comment: I created them via layout->addStretch() which creates a QSpacer with stretch = 0. Setting it to 1 doesn't change anything. To make this clear: the center widget is a subclass of QWidget which generates n folderbuttons at runtime and it has a QSpacer on top and at bottom. This combined widget is supposed to be the only resizable thingy at all.

Comment: Of course, central widget has stretch == 1? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Of course it has :) Im out of ideas, too. Resizing the central widget manually in the parents resize event works for now. Maybe I can create a small sample project here within the next few days and solve this issue in a better way. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: What is the size policy of the widgets?  Is the central widget set to be able to be resized vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few days of serious *wtf!?* I found out the reason why my widgets did not resize properly. I still do not know *why* this happens, so if someone was kind enough to explain it to me, his answer will be marked as correct instead of mine.

Facts:

- size policies were correct
- stretch factors were correct

I added the three widgets on my main widget like this:

```
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
this->setLayout(layout);
layout->addWidget(recent, 0, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->addWidget(list, 1, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->addWidget(root, 0, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignCenter);
```

As soon as I removed the alignment stuff, everything works as expected:

```
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
this->setLayout(layout);
layout->addWidget(recent);
layout->addWidget(list);
layout->addWidget(root);
```